# Blur image with pixastic and set it as background with jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, canvas

i have a problem that is bothering me form 2 days.

I'm developing a little music sharing site and i have a problem making the design for the player.

I want to apply a blurred image background to a div with CSS and with the blur begin applied on the image via JS all with pixastic js library. The problem is that pixastic gives me a HTMLImageElement witch i can't apply to a css with `$('.footer').css('background', "url(" + img.toDataURL("image/png")+ ")" });` since toDataURL works only with canvas elements.
How can i do that?

My code so far is:

```
 var img = new Image();
    img.src = '<?php echo $hd ?>';
    img.onload = function() {
    Pixastic.process(img, "blurfast", {amount:1});
    }

    $('.footer').css('background', "url(" + img.toDataURL("image/png")+ ")" });
```

The `$hd` is a http url that points to an album artwork using lastfm API

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about first argument of css method and why you dont use `img.src` as url of image? Try something like this:

```
$('.footer').css('background-image', 'url(' + img.src + ')');
```

Ok I found probably answer on documentation:

```
var options = {};
Pixastic.process(image, "action", options);
options.resultCanvas; // <- holds new canvas
```

So in your case it would be:

```
var img = new Image(),
    options = {};

options.amount = 1
img.src = '<?php echo $hd ?>';
img.onload = function() {
    Pixastic.process(img, "blurfast", options);
    $('.footer').css('background', "url(" + options.resultCanvas.toDataURL("image/png")+ ")" });
}
```

Comment: The problem is that if i do `img.src` I simply get back the original image url, without the blur effect, i'm asking for a method to get the url of the blurried image if i can, or convert the image to a canvas

Comment: And you can't put put image in background as image, with position absolute z-index -1 etc. to simulate *background*?

Comment: What do you mean? put the blurried canvas (image) on the div and then set it's z-index?

Comment: Umm, I got a `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toDataURL' of undefined` error, :/

Comment: I moved line with css method inside `onload` method. Try now. Also look what is it in `options` with `console.log`

Comment: Now options holds {amount:1} but now i get a Uncaught Error: SecurityError: DOM Exception 18, is it related to the fact that the images are not local?

Comment: Well I see here one problem. You need first add `img` to document before using Pixasting add class with `display:none` and put somewhere in document and then use Pixastic and background:)

Comment: Yeah, i now remembered that canvas can only operate with local files and not remote files (:/). P.S. how do I 'src' the image in JS after loaded it in html (as you suggested)?